Windows Server 2022 does not reboot after automatic updates
Using
gpedit.msc > Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update > Configure Automatic Updates is enabled.
Option 4 = Automatically download updates and install them on the schedule specified below.
Scheduled Install Day 1 - Every Sunday
Scheduled Install Time 2200
Every Week

Windows System Setting Automatic Updates we have Automatically Adjust Active Hours = Off
Active Hours are set to 2300-1700
All of these setting are for this server only. The server has one hour to reboot from 2200 until Active Hours begin 2300
Updates are installed but the server doesn't reboot. I'm left with the message Your device needs to restart to install updates.
What have I missed in configuration to make the server reboot after installing at 2200?
EDIT 1 Relevant bits to my untrained the of the Windows Update Log shows
2024/06/24 20:48:00.4891347 10732 15416 ComApi          GetUpdateDeploymentStatusFromDeploymentProvider call for update 4FD0C6FE-1F2D-4B1F-A588-EF925D55AEED.1 from handler returned Commit required = Yes, Reboot required = Yes

and
2024/06/24 20:58:00.0822410 7084  6612  IdleTimer       Idle timer disabled in preparation for service shutdown

but I cannot see in the logs anything to show an attempt to restart failing. Below is an extract from the log covering the end of the update installation to the end of the log:
2024/06/24 20:48:00.4867376 10732 15416 Handler         Update status code is 0xD000002D
2024/06/24 20:48:00.4867389 10732 15416 Handler         Update is not committed yet
2024/06/24 20:48:00.4888952 10732 15416 Handler         Leave GetPostRebootResult for Deployment handler
2024/06/24 20:48:00.4890486 10732 15416 Deployment      QueryUpdateDeploymentStatusInternal status for update 4fd0c6fe-1f2d-4b1f-a588-ef925d55aeed.1 : callback code = Update success, error code = 0x00242015, extended error code = 0x00000000
2024/06/24 20:48:00.4891189 10732 15416 Deployment      QueryUpdateDeploymentStatus exited with hr = 0x00000000
2024/06/24 20:48:00.4891232 10732 15416 ComApi          QueryUpdateDeploymentStatus call for update 4FD0C6FE-1F2D-4B1F-A588-EF925D55AEED.1 succeeded
2024/06/24 20:48:00.4891347 10732 15416 ComApi          GetUpdateDeploymentStatusFromDeploymentProvider call for update 4FD0C6FE-1F2D-4B1F-A588-EF925D55AEED.1 from handler returned Commit required = Yes, Reboot required = Yes
2024/06/24 20:48:00.5721317 10732 12668 ComApi          Serializing CUpdate 3F642AF9-1872-4F99-A129-06F11E2B4244.2, Last modified time 2024-06-24T18:49:09Z
2024/06/24 20:48:00.5721934 10732 12668 ComApi          Update serialization complete. BSTR byte length = 2359
2024/06/24 20:48:00.5794521 10732 12668 ComApi          Serializing CUpdate 4FD0C6FE-1F2D-4B1F-A588-EF925D55AEED.1, Last modified time 2024-06-24T18:49:09Z
2024/06/24 20:48:00.6306986 10732 12668 ComApi          Update serialization complete. BSTR byte length = 3973233
2024/06/24 20:57:59.0660940 7084  14640 Agent           Earliest future timer found: 
2024/06/24 20:57:59.0661015 7084  14640 Agent               Timer: 29A863E7-8609-4D1E-B7CD-5668F857F1DB, Expires 2024-06-25 11:18:53, not idle-only, not network-only
2024/06/24 20:58:00.0821135 7084  6612  Shared          UninitializeSUS
2024/06/24 20:58:00.0821173 7084  6612  Misc            CSusClientGlobal::DoServicePreShutdown
2024/06/24 20:58:00.0822410 7084  6612  IdleTimer       Idle timer disabled in preparation for service shutdown
2024/06/24 20:58:00.0822487 7084  6612  Misc            WUTaskManager uninit
2024/06/24 20:58:00.0822518 7084  6612  Agent           Earliest future timer found: 
2024/06/24 20:58:00.0822578 7084  6612  Agent               Timer: 29A863E7-8609-4D1E-B7CD-5668F857F1DB, Expires 2024-06-25 11:18:53, not idle-only, not network-only
2024/06/24 20:58:00.0850063 7084  6612  Misc            CreateSessionStateChangeTrigger, TYPE:2, Enable:Yes
2024/06/24 20:58:00.0850129 7084  6612  Misc            CreateSessionStateChangeTrigger, TYPE:4, Enable:Yes
2024/06/24 20:58:00.1071153 7084  6612  Misc            Agent uninit
2024/06/24 20:58:00.1071766 7084  6612  DownloadManager Exiting CDownloadHandlerCallbackHandler::Uninit within timeout bounds
2024/06/24 20:58:00.1077161 7084  6612  Misc            Reporter uninit
2024/06/24 20:58:00.1077819 7084  6612  Misc            network cost manager uninit
2024/06/24 20:58:00.1077897 7084  6612  Misc            Eventer uninit
2024/06/24 20:58:01.1125210 7084  6612  Misc            ServiceManager uninit
2024/06/24 20:58:01.1125847 7084  6612  Misc            PersistentTimeoutScheduler uninit
2024/06/24 20:58:01.1125918 7084  6612  Agent               Timer: 7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D, Expires 2024-06-24 20:49:10, not idle-only, network-only
2024/06/24 20:58:01.1134847 7084  6612  Misc            datastore uninit
2024/06/24 20:58:01.1634269 7084  6612  Misc            setting cache uninit
2024/06/24 20:58:01.1634286 7084  6612  Misc            security checker uninit
2024/06/24 20:58:01.1634337 7084  6612  Misc            Test Hook uninit
2024/06/24 20:58:01.1634343 7084  6612  Misc            IdleTimer uninit
2024/06/24 20:58:01.1637515 7084  6612  Shared          * END * Service exit Exit code = 0x240001


What is in the Windows Update log?

Windows update log extracts added in EDIT 1

The settings are configured for 22:00, the log shows entries 20:48. Seems more is off than the restart.

Why would group policy Scheduled Install Time 2200 be ignored?
